# Polar is equal to the radical axis, special case.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

In the above image, $C_0$ contains $C$ where $C$ has $OP$ as diameter and $O$ is the center of $C_0$. Also, $e$ is the polar of $P$.How can I show that $e$ is also the radical axis of both circumferences?

When $P$ is in $C_0$ or out it's easy to proof, but I'm struggling with this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly line $e$ is perpendicular to line $OP$ ( polar ) and if we define $Y$ as midpoint of $OP$ ie. centre of $C$, we also get $e \perp OY$.

Define, $X = OP \cap e$ ,and $A$ and $B$ as the tangency point from $X$ to $C_0$.

Now, it's well know that radical axis and line joining the centres are perpendicular.

And we have $OY\perp e$ at $X$ . So it's enough to show $\Bbb{P}(X,C)=\Bbb{P}(X,C_0)$ or enough to show that $XP\cdot XO= XA^2$ , which is true by similar triangles .

[image]